# find all javascript sources when using file_get_contents, then load them

Tags: php

I am trying to find out how much time it takes for url to load. For this I use `file_get_contents`:

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
$time_end = microtime(true); 
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
```

I think this way is incorrect because it wont load any of the javascript sources. I was thinking if I could somehow scan urls source code for javascript sources, then open each javascript source and get the time it took to load, then combine each javascript source loading time with `file_get_content` loading time - I would get a *somewhat more accurate* result than I have now.

I also tried few other methods using curl, javascript, iframes but all of them had problems (unrealistic results or crashes).

Edit: I need to write a script, i know there are many tools available for this (did i mention anywhere im looking for a tool?).

Edit2: Ok, after hours of reasearch i found something that i think might help me - i need to create dom file using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net , then find all javascript elements and get all src from them. I dont know why noone suggested using this earlier.

Comment: What exactly is this for? You could use something like Selenium to load the pages and track how long it takes. That would be *much* more realistic.

Comment: Chrome > F12 > network > read the bottom of the tab where it tells you the number of requests, total size, total time to load, total time for DOM content to load.

Comment: What about images, css and connection blocking?

Comment: You can have a more accurate measure using PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: I know there are many tools for this.. my assighment was to make a script that would do this.

Comment: If this is on the Internet then the connection between machines is going to be much faster than a personal computer with web server, so your results will not be accurate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of reasearch i found something that i think might help me - i need to create dom file using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net , then find all javascript elements and get all src from them. I dont know why noone suggested using this earlier.